# How to add new column after a custom column existing at the DB

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

I want to add new Column with Migration after a custom column, for example I have this table structure:

[Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVV2A.png)

And now I need to add a new column named `badge` after the `prd_description` (column 14).

So I ran `php artisan make:migration add_badge_to_products_table --table=products`

And here it goes:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->tinyInteger('badge')->unsigned()->nullable();
        });
    }
```

But now the problem is, I don't know how to add this column after that particular column. Because by default, Laravel adds this at the end of table.

So how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use after method as bellow

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->tinyInteger('badge')->unsigned()->nullable()->after('prd_description');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add column after a single specific column Like,

```
  Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->tinyInteger('badge')->after('prd_description')->unsigned()->nullable();
    });
```

Also Add Mulitple column Like this,
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-order